# References/Papers on analytic solutions to SDEs

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

Does anyone know of any good references/research papers on finding analytic solutions to stochastic differential equations and/or finding approximating solutions to such a system?

I am particularly interested in the steady-state solutions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This book](http://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/SDE.course.pdf) by Lawrence Evans at Berkeley should be enough.